# Anti Ghostping event

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I tried to make a Anti Ghostping event but it don't works and show no errors

> **Code:**

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        return
    else:
        print(member.name)
        ghostping = discord.Embed(title=f'GHOSTPING', color=0xFF0000, timestamp=message.created_at)
        ghostping.add_field(name='**Name:**', value=f'{message.author} ({message.author.id})')
        ghostping.add_field(name='**Message:**', value=f'{message.content}')
        ghostping.set_thumbnail(
            url='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTXtzZMvleC8FG1ExS4PyhFUm9kS4BGVlsTYw&usqp=CAU')
        try:
            await message.channel.send(embed=ghostping)
        except discord.Forbidden:
            try:
                await member.send(embed=ghostping)
            except discord.Forbidden:
                return
```

Comment: Do you have anything before? You may need `@client.event` In addition, you might not be able to pass in member. Check if any member of the server is in the mentions. Also you need to do `await message.channel.send(embed = ghostping)`

Comment: I did it before i just not pasted it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if len(message.mentions) == 0:
        return
    else:
        print(message.author.name)
        ghostping = discord.Embed(title=f'GHOSTPING', color=0xFF0000, timestamp=message.created_at)
        ghostping.add_field(name='**Name:**', value=f'{message.author} ({message.author.id})')
        ghostping.add_field(name='**Message:**', value=f'{message.content}')
        ghostping.set_thumbnail(
            url='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTXtzZMvleC8FG1ExS4PyhFUm9kS4BGVlsTYw&usqp=CAU')
        try:
            await message.channel.send(embed=ghostping)
        except discord.Forbidden:
            try:
                await message.author.send(embed=ghostping)
            except discord.Forbidden:
                return
```

EDIT #1: I forgot to change `member` to `message.author`